# Speeding up custom adaptive smoothen filter with opencv in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, convolution

I am new in Image Processing and trying to implement a custom filter I found in bibliography. I need to implement this in Python with opencv, but my implementation, though correct, is running really slowly. The algorithm can be described as follows:

1. Calculate normalized chromatic distances in a 3x3 neighborhood around a centre point
   `d_i = (|R_centre-R_i|+|G_centre-G_i|+|B_centre-B_i|)/(3x255)` where centre point is the current pixel that iterates through whole picture, and `i` are the 8 points around it
2. Having calculated values d_0 through d_7 we calculate an array of 8 elements called `c_i = (1-d_i)^10` which will be the values used in our convolution box
3. Our final convolution mask will be `(1/sum(c))*([c_0, c_1, c_2; c_3, 0 , c_4; c_5, c_6, c_7])` so basically `c` calues will be around and the centre point will be 0, and this matrix will be multiplied with the 9 pixels in the original image.
4. Finally repeat the whole process for as many as **iterations** variables declares, usually around 10

For an image of size 677x450 it takes around 1 minute, which I think is too much. What could change to take better advantage of numpy's functionality, or anything else that would help speed it up?

As we can see from the photos the result is a lot more smooth, even after only 2 iterations

[image: original photo]
[image: adaptive smoothening]

The code is as follows:

```
def adaptive_smoothening(img, iterations):
    M, N, K = img.shape  # M: HEIGHT, N:WIDTH, K:CHANNELS
    F = np.zeros([M, N, K], dtype=np.uint8)
    for p in range(iterations):
        print("Iteration ", p + 1)
        r = img[:, :, 2]
        g = img[:, :, 1]
        b = img[:, :, 0]
        m, n = r.shape  # m: height/channel , n: width/channel
        c = np.zeros([8, 1])
        d = np.zeros([8, 1])
        for i in range(1, m):
            for j in range(1, n):
                # Creating Neighborhood Indices
                ip = i + 1
                im = i - 1
                jm = j - 1
                jp = j + 1
                if im < 1:
                    im = i
                elif ip > m - 1:
                    ip = i - 1
                if jm < 1:
                    jm = j
                elif jp > n - 1:
                    jp = j - 1
                d[0] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[i, jm])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[i, jm])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[i, jm])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[1] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[i, jp])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[i, jp])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[i, jp])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[2] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[ip, j])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[ip, j])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[ip, j])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[3] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[im, j])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[im, j])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[im, j])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[4] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[im, jm])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[im, jm])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[im, jm])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[5] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[ip, jm])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[ip, jm])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[ip, jm])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[6] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[ip, jp])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[ip, jp])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[ip, jp])))) / (3 * 255)
                d[7] = (abs(int(r[i, j]) - int(r[im, jp])) + abs(int(g[i, j]) - int(g[im, jp])) + abs(
                    int(b[i, j] - int(b[im, jp])))) / (3 * 255)
                c = [pow(1 - float(x), 10) for x in d]
                sum2 = sum(c)
                F[i, j, 2] = (1 / sum2) * (
                        c[0] * r[i, jm] + c[1] * r[i, jp] + c[2] * r[ip, j] + c[3] * r[im, j] + c[4] * r[im, jm] +
                        c[5] * r[ip, jm] + c[6] * r[ip, jp] + c[7] * r[im, jp])
                F[i, j, 1] = (1 / sum2) * (
                        c[0] * g[i, jm] + c[1] * g[i, jp] + c[2] * g[ip, j] + c[3] * g[im, j] + c[4] * g[im, jm] +
                        c[5] * g[ip, jm] + c[6] * g[ip, jp] + c[7] * g[im, jp])
                F[i, j, 0] = (1 / sum2) * (
                        c[0] * b[i, jm] + c[1] * b[i, jp] + c[2] * b[ip, j] + c[3] * b[im, j] + c[4] * b[im, jm] +
                        c[5] * b[ip, jm] + c[6] * b[ip, jp] + c[7] * b[im, jp])
        img=F
    return F

image = cv2.imread("HorVerTextDoc 001.jpg", 1 )
cv2.imshow("Original", resize(image, 0.5) )
result = adaptive_smoothening(resize(image,0.5),2)
cv2.imshow("Result",result)
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. It's not possible to tell you what to improve in code we can't see.

Comment: @KSoe *"custom filter I found in bibliography"* can you please provide the link to the source?

Comment: @Bilal yes sure, this is the paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ima.20174 and the filter I am talking about is paragraph II. Edge Preserving Smoothing

Comment: This process sounds like an awkward version of bilateral filtering. [OpenCV has an implementation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga9d7064d478c95d60003cf839430737ed).

Comment: What do you think about my answer @KSoe?

Comment: @Prefect Unfortunately, the result is not the same with mine and I am trying to find how I could adjust it. I also updated the original image link with the full resolution one

Comment: I also realized that my results are darker than yours, it could be about the normalization. I will check on that. But you get the idea, right?

Comment: Yes kind of. If you find anything though I'll be happy to know. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

You do not really have to *slide over* your images for your task. Instead, you can create all the [shifted](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html) version of your image, and do your calculations over them. Basically, you will be doing the same calculations at one-shot instead of iterating through all the pixels, which takes some much time.  Here is an approach:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def adaptive_smooth(img):
    img = np.pad(img,((1,1),(1,1),(0,0)),mode='reflect') # add some padding so translations do not make any problem

    rows,cols = img.shape[:2]

    F = np.zeros_like(img)

    # Translations
    img_lt  = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,-1],[0,1,-1]]),(cols,rows)) # top left
    img_t   = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,0],[0,1,-1]]),(cols,rows)) # top
    img_rt  = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,1],[0,1,-1]]),(cols,rows)) # right top
    img_l   = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,-1],[0,1,0]]),(cols,rows)) # left
    img_r   = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]),(cols,rows)) # right
    img_lb  = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,-1],[0,1,1]]),(cols,rows)) # left bottom
    img_b   = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,0],[0,1,1]]),(cols,rows)) # bottom
    img_rb  = cv2.warpAffine(img,np.float32([[1,0,1],[0,1,1]]),(cols,rows)) # right bottom




    c_0 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_lt),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10 
    c_1 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_t),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10
    c_2 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_rt),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10
    c_3 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_l),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10
    c_4 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_r),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10
    c_5 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_lb),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10
    c_6 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_b),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10
    c_7 = (1-(np.sum(np.abs(img-img_rb),axis=2)/(255*3)))**10


    # fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,sharex=True,sharey=True)
    # ax[0].imshow(c_0,cmap='gray')
    # ax[1].imshow(c_7,cmap='gray')
    # plt.show()
    sum2 =  c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 + c_5 + c_6 + c_7

    F = (1/np.dstack((sum2,sum2,sum2)))*(img_lt*np.dstack((c_0,c_0,c_0))+
                img_t*np.dstack((c_1,c_1,c_1))+
                img_rt*np.dstack((c_2,c_2,c_2))+
                img_l*np.dstack((c_3,c_3,c_3))+
                img_r*np.dstack((c_4,c_4,c_4))+
                img_lb*np.dstack((c_5,c_5,c_5))+
                img_b*np.dstack((c_6,c_6,c_6))+
                img_rb*np.dstack((c_7,c_7,c_7)))


    return F[1:-1,1:-1,:] # remove padding

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("my_image.jpg", 1),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
F = adaptive_smooth(img) # 1st iteration


for _ in range(3): # 3 more iterations
    F = adaptive_smooth(F)

F[:,:,0] = F[:,:,0]/F[:,:,0].max() # Normalize channels
F[:,:,1] = F[:,:,1]/F[:,:,1].max()
F[:,:,2] = F[:,:,2]/F[:,:,2].max()


fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,sharex=True,sharey=True)
ax[0].imshow(img,cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow((F*255).astype(int),cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image: adaptive_smooth_4_times]

This image is smoothed 4 times. I hope the code is self explanatory.

EDIT: There we go. I made a mistake with `sum2` in the previous version. Also I removed the data type switches in your solution, e.g., `int` to `float` at the arrays `c` and `d`. Please add them in case this is necessary for your solution.

Comment: Looks great, exactly what I was thinking